# Fonts in R plots

Tags: graphics, r, fonts

What graphics devices let me use system fonts for text within charts? The base graphics system only has a small amount of documentation around the `par(family=...)` options.

Ideally I'd like to be able to use any font I can browse through a tool like `xfontsel` on Linux or the equivalent utilities on other platforms.

My current solution is to plot out as PDF and then use a 3rd party program to replace the fonts from within the PDF. This is not ideal.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

A list of fonts is available to the `pdf()` command, like this:

```
> names(pdfFonts())
 [1] "serif"                "sans"                 "mono"                
 [4] "AvantGarde"           "Bookman"              "Courier"             
 [7] "Helvetica"            "Helvetica-Narrow"     "NewCenturySchoolbook"
[10] "Palatino"             "Times"                "URWGothic"           
... etc ...
```

To use when creating a PDF, for example:

```
> pdf(file="plot.pdf",family="Palatino", pointsize=16, width=16,height=10)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use system fonts with [`cairo_pdf`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/cairo.html). On Ubuntu (and many other types of Linux, I guess), the `family` argument takes any font name you see in [`fc-list`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/fc-list.1.html).

Alternatively, you can use the [`extrafont`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extrafont/) package. This will allow you to use any system font with the regular [`pdf`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html) device.