# How to use Times new Roman font in grid.text()?

Tags: r, fonts

I m plotting one stacked bar plot where i need to write legend and title in Times New Roman Font. By Default it is in Arial font. How can i change it?

```
grid.text("title", x = 0.33, y = 1, just = c("left", "top"),
           gp = gpar(fontsize = 18, fontface = "bold"))
```

I used one more parameter `fontfamily =  "Times"` but i get error message. How can i use Times font with it?

Regards

Comment: did you put the argument `fontfamily` inside the call to `grid.text` or inside `gpar`? Because `grid.text("title", x = 0.33, y = 1, just = c("left", "top"), gp = gpar(fontsize = 18, fontface = "bold", fontfamily="Times"))` works for me but `grid.text("title", x = 0.33, y = 1, just = c("left", "top"), gp = gpar(fontsize = 18, fontface = "bold"), fontfamily="Times")` throws an error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `font=` instead of `fontfamily=`.

For more information, see the blog, [*Specifying Fonts in R*](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/%7Epaul/R/fonts.html), by Paul Murrell, The University of Auckland. Also see [*Changing the fonts in R plots*](https://www.r-bloggers.com/changing-the-fonts-in-r-plots/), by James Keirstead.

This question is similar to another SO question, [**Fonts in R plots**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395323/fonts-in-r-plots).

Comment: I have a dataframe where the last column is the sum of the other columns. I just want to make it bold. how is it possible.

Comment: @ArunRaja: if you want answers to questions, then writing a comment like this is not the way to do it. This comment is buried, and likely only you and I will ever see it. Instead, use the "Ask Question" button above. Write a clear and detailed question. Then everybody on StackOverflow has a chance to answer you.

Comment: I have asked the question but got a negative response I dont know why. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340345/make-first-and-last-row-of-a-dataframe-bold-using-tablegrob