# specifying font size in R figures

Tags: r, font-size

Is there a method for specifying the font size in when producing figures in R. This seems like a really basic requirement but I can't seem to find any references to somewhere that specifies the font size. I can save a figure to a pdf as follows:

```
setwd("C:\\")
pdf(file="Plot.pdf",family="Times")
plot(x,y);
dev.off()
```

Where R basically generates the figure in the pdf not in the figure window. When I look for ways of altering the font size all I see is people referring to cex=1.5 argument to scale fonts 150 percent, and cex.lab, cex.axis, etc ... Although not being an immediate issue now, I do wonder what will happen when I publish some results and the journal requires font size between 9 and 11. How do I control these in R? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `?cex` -- not exactly font size, but might serve the purpose

Comment: I think this is covered well in this answer [in this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395323/fonts-in-r-plots)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You control the font size with the `ps` (point size) parameter. The default is typically `12` (but can be controlled globally for a PDF file by the `pointsize` parameter) so if you want, let's say, fonts of the size `10` for a particular text you would use `par(ps=10); text(...)`. Since you mentioned `cex`: note that `cex` is relative to the current pointsize and also applies to symbols whereas `ps` specifically applies to text. Obviously, the size will only match as long as you don't resize the resulting figure.