# Why do cat and text handle spaces differently?

Tags: r, graphics

I am trying to plot some summary information as text on a plot, using the `text` function. What I do not understand is why `text` interprets spaces differently than `cat`.

Simple exmaple:

```
spaces <- function(x) paste(rep(" ", x), collapse = "")
vals <- c(1000, 5)
e <- paste0(spaces(3), "val1", spaces(8), "val2\n",
            "v: ", vals[1], spaces(12 - nchar(vals[1])), vals[2])

> cat(e) # Gives exactly the output I want
   val1        val2
v: 1000        5

plot(0, type = "n", bty = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", ylab = "", 
     xlab = "", xlim = c(0, 5), ylim = c(0, 5))
text(y = 4, x = 1, labels = e, adj = c(0, 1))
```

[image: <code>text</code> does not handle the spaces correctly.]

As you can see, `text` does not handle the spaces the same as the console output. I want things to line up nicely, like they do in the console output. How can I modify the object, or the call to `text` so that the plotted version mirrors the console output?

I also tried using:

```
spaces <- function(x) paste(rep("\t", x), collapse = "")
```

Comment: Your image uses a [proportional font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_font#Proportional_font); `cat`, when outputting to a typical terminal, does not.

Comment: Do you know how to make `text` not use a proportional font?

Comment: Google turned up an SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395323/fonts-in-r-plots. You'd want to use the generic "mono" or "Courier" (they are probably the same font).

Comment: @Jongware If you want to post that as an answer I will happily accept. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Nah, go ahead and award them to yourself. All I had was a hunch plus Google. I've never used R myself so this is the very limit of what I *could* do to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the very helpful comments from @Jongware, setting `par$family` works well for my purposes:

```
par(family = "mono")
plot(0, type = "n", bty = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", ylab = "", 
     xlab = "", xlim = c(0, 5), ylim = c(0, 5))
text(y = 4, x = 1, labels = e, adj = c(0, 1))
```

[image]